# Mysql table simultaneous update of rows in single table

Tags: python, mysql, locking

My python application is doing update on columns of a large mysql table. I am running multiple instances of same application to make the update process faster. Suppose I have 13 lac records. I am running 13 instances of same application:

1st instance update: 0-1 lac 
2nd instance updating : 1-2 lac
....
...so on..

When I am running my code, I am getting following error:

```
raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

Can anyone please tell how can I correct this?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words, it makes it difficult to understand for non-Indians. Do you mean with your lakh examples that each process is responsible for part of the table or something totally different? Maybe the fastening is a typo, and you're saying to make it faster?

Comment: I have updated the question. I hope it is clear now. You are right, I want make the process faster and each process is responsible for the part of the table.

Comment: Is your table InnoDB or ISAM? If it's _not_ InnoDB, then every update locks the whole table, so your multiple instances won't help "make it faster". https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/internal-locking.html